# Oracle SQL Developer - Error: "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Tags: sql, oracle

Sorry for my noob question but I'm trying to figure out why my Oracle-SQL indicates the error
**"FROM keyword not found where expected"** as the picture below:

[image]

The code I'm trying to run is the following:

```
select  
   PCKCOO AS 'COMPANHIA_DO_PEDIDO_NUMERO_DO_PEDIDO',
   PCDOCO AS 'DOCUMENTO_NUMERO_DA_OS_FATURA',
   PCDCTO AS 'TIPO_DE_ORDEM',
   PCSFXO AS 'SUFIXO_DO_PEDIDO',
   rpad(HORDT,'0',6) AS 'HORARIO_DE_LIBERACAO',
   FX_PARA_GREGORIANA(HORDJ, 'DD/MM/YYYY')||' '||rpad(HORDT,6,'0') "APROVACAO",
   rank() over (partition by pckcoo, pcdoco, pcdcto, pclnid order by FX_PARA_GREGORIANA(HORDJ, 'DD/MM/YYYY')||' '||rpad(HORDT,6,'0') desc) as rank,
   FROM PRODDTA.F5543170 a,
        proddta.f4209 b,
        proddta.f4301 c,  
   WHERE 
   PCKCOO = '52171' AND
   PCDCTO In ('OP','C1','C2','FZ','OF') AND
                   ((PCTRDJ >= '117060' AND PCTRDJ <= '117090') 
                   or (PCTRDJ >= '116061' AND PCTRDJ <= '116091')
                    ) and
                    ( b.hokcoo = a.pckcoo  and
                      b.hodoco = a.pcdoco and
                      b.hodcto = a.pcdcto and
                      B.HOASTS = '2A') and
                      (c.phkcoo (+)= a.pckcoo and
                       c.phdoco (+)= COALESCE(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(PCOORN, '^(-|+)?d+(.|,)?(d+)?$')), 0)  AND
                       c.phdcto (+)= 'OR')
```

The code was a lot bigger but I cut it into pieces in order to find out why this is happening (specially regarding the 
**Line: 3** 
and 
**Column: 25** 
as the error message indicated, which for me makes no sense).

Additionally, when I erase some lines in order to get closer towards the error, the red line (as indicated in the picture) keeps in the first line.

[image]

Do you have a guess of why this is happening? (sorry for the basic question again).

Comment: You have a comma after your last select column `rank`

Comment: You also have a trailing comma after your last table `proddta.f4301 c, `

Comment: You also seem to be mixing single and double quotes for aliases, which may or not be wrong (I'm not familiar enough with Oracle to judge), it's at least inconsistent. It is also advisable to use 'modern' `join` syntax, rather than comma separated table lists. It is also good practice to qualify every attribute with the alias of it's table, so it's more obvious where eg `PCKCOO` is coming from.

Comment: remind it for the future: this error is often due to comma issue in the SELECT clause

Comment: `AS 'SUFIXO_DO_PEDIDO',` is invalid SQL. Single quotes are for string values, not for identifiers

Comment: Thank you all for the inputs! Just one more point: after correcting as you advised, I got the error " identifier is too long, *Cause: An identifier with more than 30 characters was specified. * Action: Specify at moat 30 characters. Error at Line: 2 Column: 25"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Got now...I was identifying the columns with a too large name. Corrected now! It seems it's working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a trailing comma in the last table (`proddta.f4301 c`) of `FROM` clause and should become

```
... 
FROM PRODDTA.F5543170 a,
     proddta.f4209 b,
     proddta.f4301 c  
...
```

which should be removed.

You also have a trailing comma in your select statement that should also be removed.

```
...
rank() over (partition by pckcoo, pcdoco, pcdcto, pclnid order by FX_PARA_GREGORIANA(HORDJ, 'DD/MM/YYYY')||' '||rpad(HORDT,6,'0') desc) as rank
...
```

Finally, for table alias you need to use double instead of single quotes:

```
select  
   PCKCOO AS "COMPANHIA_DO_PEDIDO_NUMERO_DO_PEDIDO",
   PCDOCO AS "DOCUMENTO_NUMERO_DA_OS_FATURA",
   PCDCTO AS "TIPO_DE_ORDEM",
   PCSFXO AS "SUFIXO_DO_PEDIDO",
   rpad(HORDT,'0',6) AS "HORARIO_DE_LIBERACAO",
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You have some trailing commas after `AS RANK` and after `proddta.f4301 c`.

Also, you can not use single quotes for column aliases, but you need double quotes;
this should work:

```
SELECT PCKCOO AS "COMPANHIA_DO_PEDIDO_NUMERO_DO_PEDIDO",
       PCDOCO AS "DOCUMENTO_NUMERO_DA_OS_FATURA",
       PCDCTO AS "TIPO_DE_ORDEM",
       PCSFXO AS "SUFIXO_DO_PEDIDO",
       RPAD(
            HORDT,
            '0',
            6
           )
           AS "HORARIO_DE_LIBERACAO",
          FX_PARA_GREGORIANA(HORDJ, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
       || ' '
       || RPAD(
               HORDT,
               6,
               '0'
              )
           "APROVACAO",
       RANK()
           OVER(
                PARTITION BY pckcoo,
                             pcdoco,
                             pcdcto,
                             pclnid
                ORDER BY
                       FX_PARA_GREGORIANA(HORDJ, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                    || ' '
                    || RPAD(
                            HORDT,
                            6,
                            '0'
                           ) DESC
               )
           AS RANK
  FROM PRODDTA.F5543170 a,
       proddta.f4209 b,
       proddta.f4301 c
 WHERE     PCKCOO = '52171'
       AND PCDCTO IN ('OP',
                      'C1',
                      'C2',
                      'FZ',
                      'OF')
       AND (   (    PCTRDJ >= '117060'
                AND PCTRDJ <= '117090')
            OR (    PCTRDJ >= '116061'
                AND PCTRDJ <= '116091'))
       AND (    b.hokcoo = a.pckcoo
            AND b.hodoco = a.pcdoco
            AND b.hodcto = a.pcdcto
            AND B.HOASTS = '2A')
       AND (    c.phkcoo(+) = a.pckcoo
            AND c.phdoco(+) = COALESCE(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(PCOORN, '^(-|+)?d+(.|,)?(d+)?$')), 0)
            AND c.phdcto(+) = 'OR')
```

As an aside, you should better switch to ANSI JOIN syntax.